# Strange bool returing behavior

Tags: c++, boolean, compare, return

I am trying to compare two strings character by character using the `bool match(string,string)` I created, I believe it compares correctly when I enter two strings that are not equal to each other it does output false! but when I check the bool it has not returned false.
I can't think of a reason for this behavior and I hope somebody can help me.
The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool match(string pattern, string source)
{
    if(pattern.size() == 0&& source.size() == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(pattern[0] == source[0])
    {
        pattern.erase(0,1);
        source.erase(0,1);
        match(pattern,source);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "false" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
int main()
{
    string test1 = "hballo";
    string test2 = "hallo";
    bool match_found =  match(test1,test2);
    if(match_found)
    {
        cout << "match found!"<< endl;
    } 
    else if(!match_found)
    {
        cout << "match not found!"<< endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgotten a `return` in

```
pattern.erase(0,1);
source.erase(0,1);
return match(pattern,source);
^^^^^^
```

Also, as pointed out by @melpomene, the `pattern[0] == source[0]` part is broken, since `pattern` or `source` (but not both) can be empty at this point.

Finally, needs to be said that the recursive approach is extremely inefficient here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer NPE! Even though it wasn't the fastest answer I still appreciate your answer!

Comment: In addition to that, the `pattern[0] == source[0]` part is broken too. `pattern` or `source` can be empty at this point.

Comment: I am afraid the recursion is mandatory, and my goal is to compare both strings completely, this means that if one is empty and the other string is not they are not the same. Or is that just me?

Comment: @EliantenHolder: That's exactly right. The problem is that you're not handing this case correctly. Either `pattern[0]` or `source[0]` will be undefined once you've exhausted the shorter string. The first `if` will evaluate to `false`, and the `pattern[0] == source[0]` will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NPE How would you recommend solving this? Check the length of the string before comparing?

Comment: In the second `if`, check that both are non-empty before checking `(pattern[0] == source[0])`.

Comment: @NPE I added your suggestion it actually solved an other problem, Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return statement in you second else statment:

```
if(pattern.size() == 0&& source.size() == 0)
{
    return true;
}
else if(pattern[0] == source[0])  // no return statement.
{
    pattern.erase(0,1);
    source.erase(0,1);
    return match(pattern,source);
}
else
{
    cout << "false" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this implementation:

```
bool match(const string& pattern, const string& source)
{
    int len = source.size();
    if (pattern.size() != len)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (pattern[i] != source[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You meant

```
return match(pattern,source);
```

otherwise you get undefined behavior.